# Countdown to zero instead of 1?

Tags: python

```
a = int(input("Enter a numeber: "))

for i in range(a):
    x = a - i
    print(x)
```

How can I make this count down to zero instead of 1?

Comment: by `x = a - i - 1` maybe?

Comment: But then the user input will not print

Comment: You could increase the range by 1 as well.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the three-argument form of [`range`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#func-range):

```
for i in range(a, -1, -1):
     print(i)
```

It will start with `a` and then (because the step [third argument] is `-1`) count down to `0` because the stop value (`-1` [second argument]) is excluded.

Answer (score 0):

Just add 1 to your range.

Your program now looks like:

```
a = int(input("Enter a number: "))


for i in range(a+1):
    x = a - i
    print(x)
```

This is because `range(n)` goes from 0 to n-1, and so as you have it, your final iteration runs a - (a-1) = 1. To make your range go until a ( to calculate a - a ) you need to use `range(a+1)`.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Looks perfectly senseable to me +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `while-loop` like:

```
a = int(input("Enter a numeber: "))
while a >= 0:
    print(a)
    a -= 1
```

output:

```
Enter a numeber: 10
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

if you want to use a for loop you just need to use a+1 in the range:

```
a = int(input("Enter a numeber: "))
for i in range(a+1):
    print(a-i)
```

Comment: I need to use for loop range for this. While loop not allowed

Comment: @python_noob edited the answer